# как работает кнопка "открыть с помощью"

Tags: java

Я хочу написать программу на java, которая должна делать следующее:
я нажимаю ПКМ по текстовому файлу -> открыть с помошью... -> моя программа.
После чего моя программа через JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(); показывает содержимое этого файла.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Главный метод в Java-программе определен как `public static void main(String[] args) `. Нужно будет посмотреть, что `args` содержит данные, первый элемент этого массива и будет именем файла для открытия.